# I need to save the output of Print command into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, if-statement

I am using pandas to compare time durations to mark attendance.
I have used DateTime and timedelta to compare the durations. I want to save the output in the adjacent column so that we know who was present and who was not.

I can compare the values and print if the person was present or absent, but i want to do it in the excel file in front of the name of the person

```
df1 =df[['Date', 'Agent Name', 'Login Time']]

for x in df1['Login Time']:
s1 = str(x)
s2 = '12:00:00'
s3 = '3:10:00'
s4 = '01:00:00'
FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
tdelta = datetime.strptime(s2, FMT) - datetime.strptime(s1, FMT)
if x == s4:
    print('Aussi')
elif (str(tdelta)) < s3:
    print('Present')
else: 
    print('Check')
```

what i am thinking is, i will store the value of the output in a list and then add the list to a new column in the df.

Comment: Aussi
Aussi
Aussi
Aussi
Aussi
Present
Present
Present
Check
Present
Present
Check
Present
Present
Present
Present
Check
Present
Present
Present
Present
Present
Present
Present
Present
Present
Present
Present
Present
Present
Present
Check
Check
Present
Present
Check
Present
Check
Present
Present
Present
Present
Present
Present
Present
Present
This is the output

Comment: Did you try just `attendence = []` before your `for` loop and then `attendance.append(value)`, where `value` can be _Aussie_, _Present_, or _Check_?

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked!

Comment: Cool beans, I added an answer to formalize what you're looking for. If you see value in my answer, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create an empty list before your loop, and then append to it during the loop.

1. Add this before your `for` loop:

```
attendance = []
```

2. Add this inside of `for` loop, at the end, where `value` can be one of *Aussi*, *Present*, or *Check*:

```
attendance.append(value)
```

Here's what it might look like:

```
df1 =df[['Date', 'Agent Name', 'Login Time']]

attendance = []
for x in df1['Login Time']:
    s1 = str(x)
    s2 = '12:00:00'
    s3 = '3:10:00'
    s4 = '01:00:00'
    FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
    tdelta = datetime.strptime(s2, FMT) - datetime.strptime(s1, FMT)
    if x == s4:
        value = 'Aussi'
    elif (str(tdelta)) < s3:
        value = 'Present'
    else: 
        value = 'Check'
    attendance.append(value)
```